# Database schema for simple poll

Tags: mysql, schema

I am going to create simple poll for my shop customers. Poll will be display during order process so ID of customer is sufficient protection, poll will be display at first order only.

In poll will be only one question few one choice answers. One of these answers will be "custom". Customer will be able to type own answer.

I have problem how to build my database schema. I prepared this:

```
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id       | int(11)      | NO   |     |         |       |
| customer | int(11)      | NO   |     |         |       |
| answer   | varchar(160) | NO   |     |         |       |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

In answer column will be ID of selected answer or custom text which customer typed to text input.

What do you think about that solution?

Comment: Do you plan to ask a single question only?

Comment: Yes. You can choose one of some proposed answer or type own, text answer.

Comment: How will you know which answer corresponds to which question?

Comment: Yes. It is very simple solution. I would not manage answers, create new polls etc.

Comment: Or you changed your question or I wrong read :) There will be only one question, so there is no problem to know which answer coresponds to which question. Answers will be hardcoded in HTML.